# Oracle - How to calculate if the End Date of an activity is "Nearly Overdue"

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have an Activity that has a START_TIME and an END_TIME (both times are saved as Oracle **Timestamps**)

**Requirement:**
Show the activities that are "Nealry Overdue", where "Nearly Overdue" means:

Time where the query runs is **between** (**End_Date Minus a Percentage of the duration**)  **and** End_Date.

For example:

1) **Start_Time=01/02/2015**  and  **End_Time=20/02/2015**        (tot 20 days)

2) Configured percentage for activity to be considered as nearly overdue is 10%

Then: 10% of 20days(duration between start_time and end_time) =**2 days**

Which implies that if we run the query between **18/02/2015** and **20/02/2015** the Activity should result as Nearly Overdue.

**Any Idea how achieve this with a query?**

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: @Wernfried Of course but I failed.. I didn't want to add confusion that's why I didn't post any of the queries I tried.

Comment: Well, post one of them.

Comment: @Wernfried I found the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can subtract timestamps, and get the diff in days. From there on, it's just math:

```
SELECT *
FROM   mytable
WEHRE  (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - end_time) / (end_time - start_time) <= 0.1
```

Comment: when you substract timestamps it gives you the difference in days hour:minutes:seconds .

Comment: @Alboz - you can cast your timestamp columns to dates, since you don't need the precision anyway? Then you'd get the difference in days, when compared with sysdate..

Comment: @AlexPoole I solved it but what Mureinik did propose doesn't even execute(you get an error) because you can't divide the result of the subtraction. This is because the result is something like 'Days hours:minutes:seconds'

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether is useful or not but since **I managed to solve it**, I'm posting my solution:

```
SELECT *  
FROM
    JOB 
WHERE
    TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ ('29/01/2015 16:44 UTC', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:mi TZR') <=  JOB.PLANNED_END_DATE
    AND 
   TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ ('29/01/2015 16:44 UTC', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:mi TZR') > JOB.PLANNED_END_DATE - ((JOB.PLANNED_END_DATE - JOB.PLANNED_START_DATE)* 0.1);
```

**Explanation:**

`0.1` is in my case the percentage (10%) to consider something nearly overdue.

`TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ ('29/01/2015 16:44 UTC', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:mi TZR')` is the target day for which you want to know if the activities are nearly overdue.
**Usually** it's **today** so you can also subsistute it by putting `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`

In that case the query will became:

```
SELECT *  
FROM
    JOB 
WHERE
   CURRENT_TIMESTAMP <=  JOB.PLANNED_END_DATE
    AND 
   CURRENT_TIMESTAMP > JOB.PLANNED_END_DATE - ((JOB.PLANNED_END_DATE -    JOB.PLANNED_START_DATE)* 0.1);
```